# Add a properties file to war and classes jar

Tags: java, maven, jar

We use Maven war plugin to generate a war with attached classes jar. During the build, a properties file is generated. This property file should be put into the root directory of both the war and the classes jar.

Defining the properties file as "resource" implies that it goes the jar (and not war). Is there any way to put it into both artifacts?

Comment: Could you post your pom.xml?

Comment: You'll need to declare it twice. Once as a `<webResource>` for the WAR Plugin (see [this](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html), with no `<targetPath>` to put at the root of the WAR), and one to add it as a resource, like you did.